# Mysql query with conditional join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm stuck on a MySQL query. I have a temporary orders table with the following structure:

```
session_id
product_id
product_type -- 'institute','state','region','country'
```

For all `institutes`, `states`, `regions` and `countries` I have individual tables.

I want to create a MySQL query which fetches the data from my temp table and makes the join with the corresponding table depending upon `product_type` field.

If I use `left join` with 5 tables or use `union` it could be a really time consuming task; so I was looking for something different.

Comment: How do you want these joins depends upon `product_type` field? can you clarify by an example or sample data?

Comment: i want something like if the value of product_type field is institute then perform a join with institutes table,similarly if the value is value is state perform a join with the states table and so on..

Comment: If you want all the data there's no way but using `union`. [Simon's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349119/458741) mentions restructuring the database, which seems like your best bet at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

**I would advise checking the answers in this question as they seem to match your specific problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/9327678/1213554**

The short version though is that in order to be able to efficiently perform this request a database restructuring may well be required I'm afraid.

What you are looking for specifically is not possible, you'll have to use a UNION to do something along the lines of the following.  As you say it will be a time consuming task though.

```
(
    SELECT tempData.*
    FROM tempData
    INNER JOIN institutes 
    ON institutes.id = tempData.product_id
    WHERE tempData.product_type = 'institute'
) UNION (
    SELECT tempData.*
    FROM tempData
    INNER JOIN states 
    ON states.id = tempData.product_id
    WHERE tempData.product_type = 'state'
) UNION (
    SELECT tempData.*
    FROM tempData
    INNER JOIN regions
    ON regions.id = tempData.product_id
    WHERE tempData.product_type = 'region'
) UNION (
    SELECT tempData.*
    FROM tempData
    INNER JOIN countries
    ON countries.id = tempData.product_id
    WHERE tempData.product_type = 'country'
)
```